# Timing of ParallelDo versus Do: simple example

Tags: evaluation, parallelization

I'm trying to understand why a simple do-loop takes substantially longer when done in parallel than sequentially:

```
count = 0;  
SetSharedVariable[count];  
AbsoluteTiming[Do[count++, {nn, 100}]]  
Print[count]  

Out[493]= {0.000176, Null} (\*Time in seconds*)   
Out[494]= 100 (\*The result*)
```

Whereas if I do

```
count = 0;  
SetSharedVariable[count];  
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelDo[count++, {nn, 100}]]  
Print[count]  

Out[497]= {0.391256, Null}  (\*Time in seconds*)  
Out[498]= 100 (\*The result*)
```

Could someone please explain why ParallelDo takes 0.39 seconds whereas Do takes only 0.00017 seconds?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look here: [Why won't Parallelize speed up my code?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48295/12).  `SetSharedVariable` forces `count` to be always evaluated on the main kernel.  Thus you gain nothing, but you do lose a lot: evaluation will keep switching between parallel kernels and the main kernel, adding a considerable overhead.

Comment: To see what SetSharedVariable really does, evaluate `SetSharedVariable[count]` first, then `ParallelEvaluate[Information[count]]`.  It's a very straightforward implementation.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks for the helpful comment and link. So then, if I understand correctly, in order for a single variable to be updated by, say, a billion independent loops I'm better off using `Do` loops instead of `ParallelDo` loops because of the communication overhead?

Comment: Usually, yes.  The best thing is not to use a variable that's changed by multiple threads, but this is not possible for every algorithm.  When it is possible, it simplifies parallelization dramatically (in any language).  `SetSharedVariable` is only useful if the variable access is infrequent and takes negligible time compared to other computations.  I only found `SetSharedVariable` useful in very few cases.