# Speeding Up Image Processing Functions

Tags: functions, dynamic, performance-tuning, image-processing, compile

I am working with stacks of 1024x1024 timelapse microscopy images that I am performing a series of image processing functions on to help segment each image.  These functions include `Sharpen`, `Erosion`, `Dilation`, `RidgeFilter`, `FillingTransform` and `WatershedComponents` (with hand-selected markers).  After some trial and error it seems I need to at least use the following functions to arrive at a generally acceptable segmentation:

```
watershedLabelMatrix = WatershedComponents[RidgeFilter[image],markersForWatershed]
```

I would like to know if there is anyway to speed up these image processing steps (particularly the bit of code above).  I have not had success with use of `Compile` or `Parallelize`.  I am not sure if it is possible to Compile a function that takes an image as its argument.  Here's one example of what failed for me:

```
watershedCompile1 = Compile[{{imageIn, _Real}, {markersIn, _Real}},
                      WatershedComponents[imageIn, markersIn]]
```

I get this message after evaluating:

> Compile::extscalar: "WatershedComponents[imageIn,markersIn] cannot be compiled and will be evaluated externally. The result is assumed to be of type Real."

Similarly, when I try to `Parallelize` I am told `WatershedComponents` cannot be parallelized.

When I try to use `WatershedComponents` "on the fly" within a little `DynamicModule` interactive notebook I have written that iterates through a stack of images and allows me to save acceptable `WatershedComponent` masks, I get a long (maybe 5 to 10 seconds) pause while I wait for the `WatershedComponents` result and usually see the dreaded *Progress: Formatting Notebook Contents* dialog window popup.

Any suggestions on improving the performance of these image processing functions or suggestions for how to improve performance within a `DynamicModule` (or alternatives to `DynamicModule`) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Parallelize` has a somewhat misleading name.  [It won't magically speed up anything.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48295/why-wont-parallelize-speed-up-my-code)  `Compile` also supports [only certain functions,](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) and compilation likely won't help at all with these functions, it might even hurt performance a tiny bit.  This is, of course, not an answer to your question about how to speed up the operation.

Comment: Many Image Processing Functions can be accelerated by using  `CUDALink` and `OpenCLLink`. Erosion and Dilation have build in CUDA functions (`CUDAErosion`, `CUDADilation`).

Comment: Have you tried to scale down the image? Of course, it depends on your application if that works. I saw in one of your previous questions that you have a lot of nothing around the area of interest, it would probably be faster if you would `ImageCrop` to just use `WatershedComponents` on the area of interest.

Comment: I don't think there is much you can do to speed up the built-in `WatershedComponents`. It is implemented using a separate program ITK.exe which I assume is an implementation of the [ITK toolkit](http://www.itk.org/). I suspect paw's suggestion to use GPU processing might be the best approach to getting performance fast enough for a dynamic interface. A Google search for *watershed components gpu* gets some interesting looking results.

Comment: @Pickett I haven't tried cropping the images but resizing them from 1024x1024 to 512x512 does give roughly a 4-fold improvement in time for WatershedComponents to evaluate.