# Side effects with ParallelDo

Tags: parallelization

Hi guys I've the following problem with ParallelDo: if I run the code:

```
r1 = {};
r2 = {};

zmin = 6;
zmax = 9;
tpass = 1;
zpass = 0.001;

Do[

 MLEdata = Table[MLE[z, t], {z, zmin, zmax, zpass}];
 MaxPeak = Max[MLEdata];
 PosPeak = Position[MLEdata, MaxPeak];
 OverHalfPeak = Select[MLEdata, # > MaxPeak/2 &];
 NumPoints = Length[OverHalfPeak];

 AppendTo[r1, PosPeak]; 
 AppendTo[r2, NumPoints], {t, tmin, tmax, tpass}]

zPeak = zmin - zpass + r1*zpass // Flatten; (*pos. in um*)

DeltaMLE = r2 - 1; (*FWHM in nm*)

dat = Flatten /@ Transpose[{zPeak, DeltaMLE}];
Export["axial track.txt", dat, "Table"];
```

I get the values in zPeak and DeltaMLE listed in the right order, but if I use ParallelDo like this to speed up the computation:

```
r1 = {};
r2 = {};
SetShareVariable[r1,r2]

zmin = 6;
zmax = 9;
tpass = 1;
zpass = 0.001;

ParallelDo[

 MLEdata = Table[MLE[z, t], {z, zmin, zmax, zpass}];
 MaxPeak = Max[MLEdata];
 PosPeak = Position[MLEdata, MaxPeak];
 OverHalfPeak = Select[MLEdata, # > MaxPeak/2 &];
 NumPoints = Length[OverHalfPeak];

 AppendTo[r1, PosPeak]; 
 AppendTo[r2, NumPoints], {t, tmin, tmax, tpass}]

zPeak = zmin - zpass + r1*zpass // Flatten; (*pos. in um*)

DeltaMLE = r2 - 1; (*FWHM in nm*)

dat = Flatten /@ Transpose[{zPeak, DeltaMLE}];
Export["axial track.txt", dat, "Table"];
```

the order is completely wrong. I understand that there are some side effects, but I don't understand how to correct for them (I'm pretty new with the parallelization). Could you help me?

Comment: Can you explain why you are not using `Table`and avoiding side-effects (i.e. `AppendTo`) entirely?

Comment: `MLE`, `tmin` and `tmax` are missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your code, I do not see any reason not to use `Table` instead of `Do`.  Why aren't you using `(Parallel)Table`?

Disadvantages of `Do`/`ParallelDo`:

- Each call to `AppendTo[array, something]` will make a complete copy of `array`, thus it is slow.
- You must use `SetSharedVariable` to access main-kernel variables from parallel kernels.  [This kills performance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48295/why-wont-parallelize-speed-up-my-code), except when variable accesses are rare and the rest of the computation takes a long time.
- There's no guarantee about the order of evaluations with `ParallelDo`.  That's why you get results out of order.  Computations happen in parallel, and whichever finishes first will append to `r1` first.  If you really must use `Do` for this, then record `t` with the computed values as well and sort by `t` at the end.

All these problems would go away if you used `Table.`

Comment: Hi Szabolcs and thanks for the quick answer. Basically, MLE(z,t) is a two variable function, which has peaks at different positions for different t. So I use the Do to select different instants t and extract every time the peak position and the fwhm of the peak. I thought the Do was the best way to repeat the process for all the different t. How could I do the same job with Table and so ParallelTable? Tmin and tmax are two variables, where tmin<tpass<tmax.

Comment: @MicheleGuastamacchia I don't understand the question.  As far as I can see you are doing `r={}; Do[AppendTo[r,f[t]], {t, 100}]` (simplified).  That gives the same result as `Table[f[t], {t,100}]`.  What am I missing?

Comment: I see your point. Now I have a 2D nested list, how can I extract the positions of the maxima and the number of points >= than those maxima/2 (to get the fwhm's) from each sub list?

Comment: @MicheleGuastamacchia Just change `Do` to `Table` and change `AppendTo[r1, PosPeak]; 
 AppendTo[r2, NumPoints]` to `{PosPeak,NumPoints}`.  Then use `Part` and `All` to extract what you need from the result.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!