# remove unevaluated cells from table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have created a table `Tv` where each row is of the form

{x,  y,  Iv[x,y]}

where `Iv` is some complicated numerical integral and `x` and `y` iterate through some parameter space. The issue I am facing now is that for some values of `x` and `y`, `Iv[x,y]` failed to evaluate. Since these are only a few cases, I would like to continue working with the rest of the data. Unfortunately, however, when I try to print or save `Tv`, mathematica tries to re-evaluate the cells that failed before, which takes many hours (and, of course, they fail again).

So my question is: Can I remove all rows of `Tv` with non-numeric entries in the third column without re-evaluating these cells?

**Edit:**

Here is integral that gives me troubles:

```
kernel[x_, xp_, p_, d_] := 
 2 Sqrt[x^2 + xp^2 - 2 x xp Cos[p]] - 
  2 Sqrt[d^-2 + x^2 + xp^2 - 2 x xp Cos[p]] - 
  1/2 d^-1 (Log[x^2 + xp^2 - 2 x xp Cos[p]] + 
     Log[-d^-1 + Sqrt[d^-2 + x^2 + xp^2 - 2 x xp Cos[p]]] - 
     3 Log[d^-1 + Sqrt[d^-2 + x^2 + xp^2 - 2 x xp Cos[p]]])
rdivM[x_, x0_] := 
 x (-1 + (4 Sinh[x]^2)/(Cosh[2 x] + Cosh[2 x0])) (Sech[x - x0] + 
     Sech[x + x0]) + 4 Cosh[x0] Sinh[x]/(Cosh[2 x] + Cosh[2 x0])
Iv[x0_, d_] := 
 2 NIntegrate[
   rdivM[x, x0] rdivM[xp, x0] kernel[x, xp, p, d], {x, 
    Max[0, x0 - 50], x0 + 50}, {xp, Max[0, x0 - 50], x}, {p, 0, Pi}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 100000}]
```

and the evaluation:

```
x0List = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 
   15, 20, 35, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200};
logdList = Range[-4, 4, 1/10];
Tdv = ConstantArray[0, {Length[x0List]*Length[logdList], 3}];
SetSharedVariable[Tdv];
n = 0;
SetSharedVariable[n];
ParallelDo[Tdv[[d + r Length[logdList] + 1, 1]] = x0List[[r + 1]];
 Tdv[[d + r Length[logdList] + 1, 2]] = N[10^logdList[[d + 1]]];
 Tdv[[d + r Length[logdList] + 1, 3]] = 
  Re[Iv[N[x0List[[r + 1]]], N[10^logdList[[d + 1]]]]]; n++; 
 Print[n], {r, 0, Length[x0List] - 1}, {d, 0, Length[logdList] - 1}]
```

The evaluation will take many hours, but you can abort after a the first error messages. Then just try to print `Tdv`.

Comment: You can probably use a combination of `If[]` and `Nothing` for this.

Comment: How would I do this without re-evaluating the cells? So far, every operation on `Tv` has lead to a re-evaluation of failed cells.

Comment: You may have to re-factor the structure of your calculation to avoid shared variables in parallel calculations. See: [Side effects with ParallelDo](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107685/27951) and [Why won't Parallelize speed up my code?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48296/27951).

Comment: I have no problem with the performance of the ParallelDo[...] code. Also, I don't use Append[...] and the data that is evaluated seems to be all consistent. The problem is only about the fraction of the data that fails to calculate (it also fails when I evaluate it outside the ParallelDo[...] loop).

Comment: @Felix, take a look at a different approach I show in a new answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the call to the function that is likely to generate errors and return unevaluated in a [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html) expression. In the case of correct execution, `Check` will pass through the value returned by its argument; in case of an error, it will return an expression of your choice.

This "failure indicator" won't trigger recalculation, and can be made very recognizable so it will be easy to remove data points that contain it. Two such examples could be [`$Failed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Failed.html) or [`Missing[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Missing.html). I prefer the latter, since it naturally works well with the [`DeleteMissing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteMissing.html) command.

In short, I propose the following modification in your `ParallelDo` code:

```
Tdv[[d + r Length[logdList] + 1, 3]] = 
  Check[
    Re[Iv[N[x0List[[r + 1]]], N[10^logdList[[d + 1]]]]], 
    Missing[], 
    {Infinity::indet, NIntegrate::inumri}
  ];
```

In those cases where errors as `Infinity::indet` or `NIntegrate::inumri` (i.e. the integrand has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region) are generated by the calculation, `Missing[]` will be returned.

Here is a sample obtained from running the modified code for a while, then aborting it, and evaluating `Tdv`:

```
{ {0, 0.0001, Missing[]}, {0, 0.000125893, 6.11017*10^6}, 
  {0, 0.000158489, 4.7075*10^6}, .... , {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0.0001, Missing[]}, {1, 0.000125893, 7.75528*10^6}, 
  {1, 0.000158489, 5.9716*10^6}, .... }
```

Since no unevaluated `NIntegrate` expression was left behind, no re-evaluation was triggered.

You can then remove the "bad" points using `DeleteMissing` with an appropriate level specification:

```
DeleteMissing[Tdv, 1, Infinity]

{ {0, 0.000125893, 6.11017*10^6}, 
  {0, 0.000158489, 4.7075*10^6}, .... , {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0.000125893, 7.75528*10^6}, 
  {1, 0.000158489, 5.9716*10^6}, .... }
```

---

Following up on your comment looking for a way to **prevent re-evaluation "after the fact"**, i.e. on a list of results that were generated without the `Check`, you can achieve that as well.

The simplest way I can think of is to **temporarily redefine the function whose evaluation you want to prevent**. You can do that with a local definition within the scope of a `Block`, as follows (here `Tdv` is the result of a partial evaluation as used above):

```
Block[{NIntegrate = Inactive[NIntegrate]},
  Tdv
]
```

[image: inactivated results]

This effectively prevents evaluation of `NIntegrate` so wastes no time.

You can also use this to filter out the unwanted unevaluated results:

```
cleanTdv = Block[{NIntegrate = Inactive[NIntegrate]},
  Cases[Tdv, {_, _, _?NumericQ}]
]
```

[image: no NIntegrate any more]

Comment: That is a very helpful approach. Following it, I now recalculated the entire table `Tdv`. Still, out of curiosity: Would it have been possible to apply this solution to the table *after* its evaluation with the original code? Like, if one happens to run the code without the Check function for some time, is there a way to recover the result without having to re-evaluate?

Comment: @Felix Yes you can do that as well. I have added such an approach as a second part to my answer above.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed.