# How to successfully put a ParallelDo loop inside a Do loop?

Tags: parallelization

I'm trying to set up a `ParallelDo` loop inside of a `Do` loop, however I'm running into issues. Here is a very simplified toy model code of the final code that I wish to implement:

```
LaunchKernels[16];

ParallelEvaluate[

n[i_] = {};

M[i_] = {};

Do[ 
   AppendTo[n[i],{0,0}];
   AppendTo[M[i],{0,0}],
   {i,1,5}
  ]

];

Do[
   ParallelDo[
    J1[i] = {i, j}; 
    J2[i] = {i + 1, j + 1}; 
    AppendTo[M[i], J1[i]]; 
    AppendTo[n[i], J2[i]],
    {i, 1, 5}
   ],
  {j, 0, 5}
]
```

The problem seems to be that Mathematica appends to the initial conditions to a given `n[i]` (or `M[i]`) as many times as there are parallel kernels. For example,

```
Join@@ParallelEvaluate[n[1]] = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 
                               {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 
                               {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 
                               {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3},
                               {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}}
```

And so Mathematica duplicates the initial conditions that it `AppendsTo` a particular `n[i]` (or `M[i]`) 16 times over.

Why is this happening and what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: are you trying to set it up so that `n`, `M`, `J1` and `J2` are synchronized? If so see `SetSharedVariable`. This might provide a slow-down though. Better to initialize each chunk separately, I think so that it's right in the end. Oh, or are you trying to get the code in the `ParallelDo` to happen on all kernels? Then just use `ParallelEvaluate` and `Do.

Comment: @MB1965        The problem is that I want the inner most `Do` loop to be parallelised, i.e. like you say, I want the computations in the `ParallelDo`  to be distributed among the kernels. The outer one needs to be a "normal" `Do` loop since the results might depend on previous calculations.

Comment: Use `SetSharedVariable` then. Based on what you say I think that's what you want.

Comment: @MB1965        Ah ok. So do I just move the `ParallelEvaluate` completely and just put `SetSharedVariable[n[i], M[i]]`?

Comment: just `SetSharedVariable[n,M]` I think.

Comment: @MB1965        Ok, I'll give that a go. I think I might run into issues though since in the full calculation that I'm doing `n[i]` and `M[i]` are more complicated functions and each kernel will require knowledge of their functional forms and the associated parameters.

Comment: There's also `SetSharedFunction`. In any case between those two and partitioning the work cleverly you can almost certainly find your solution.

Comment: @MB1965        Ok thanks for the advice.

Comment: `SetSharedFunction` is what you need to make this code work.  I'd suggest it would be preferable to use `ParallelTable` and avoid `AppendTo`

Comment: This is not the right approach to parallelization. Please read [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48295/12) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138909/12).  `Do` + `AppendTo` is generally a bad approach in Mathematica, particularly so with parallelization.  Use `Table` instead.

Comment: @Szabolcs      Thanks for the information. I'm quite new to using parallelisation techniques so apologies for my shoddy code.