# ParallelSum vs. Sum: New functions also defined in other Kernels?

Tags: functions, parallelization, summation, variable-definitions

**Set-Up**: While I had tested a few toy examples that  ParallelSum produces the result faster than the Sum, here I encounter one example in my code that the ParallelSum produces either wrong/incorrect result or a warning message. My code below has some new function definitions. (In reality, my complete code has more complicated functions and mappings, but I try to boil down to something simpler to save your energy for your review.)

```
A_ ⊕ B_ := 
  Mod[{A[[1]] + B[[1]] + A[[2]] B[[3]], A[[2]] + B[[2]], 
    A[[3]] + B[[3]]}, 2];

Conv[m_] := IntegerDigits[Mod[m, 8], 2, 3];
SumD[n_, o_] := (fF[Conv[n]⊕Conv[o]])
Do[fF[IntegerDigits[j, 2, 3]] = j, {j, 0, 7}]

Mapp[0] = {0, 0}; 
Mapp[1] = {0, 1}; 
Mapp[2] = {1, 0}; 
Mapp[3] = {1, 1};
```

While the Sum

```
Sum[Mapp[SumD[a, b]][[2]], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

works and it produces the correct result 2,

the ParallelSum

```
ParallelSum[Mapp[SumD[a, b]][[2]], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

does **not** produce the correct result. **It actually produces wrong result if I make a list of a large number of summations.**

It says the 
[image]

**Question**: I am guessing the following --- Some of the functions defined by me in the earlier part of my code, they are ONLY defined in the Kernel 1, but not defined in other Kernels? Am I correct? How do we modify it to make the ParallelSum work well? [especially I need the ParallelSum, for a list of a large number of summations not shown in my shortened code above.]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see that how ParallelSum can speed up the Sum as my examples here:

Comment: Timing[Sum[
  If[MatchQ[Mod[i + j, 8], 0 | 2 | 4] && 
    MatchQ[Mod[j + k, 8], 0 | 2 | 4] && 
    MatchQ[Mod[i + k, 8], 
     0 | 2 | 4] && (i^2 + j^2 > k^2) && (j^2 + k^2 > 
      i^2) && (i^2 + k^2 > j^2), f[i, j, k], 0], {i, 0, 2^10}, {j, 0, 
   2^10}, {k, 1, 2^2 + 1}]];

Comment: Timing[ParallelSum[
  If[MatchQ[Mod[i + j, 8], 0 | 2 | 4] && 
    MatchQ[Mod[j + k, 8], 0 | 2 | 4] && 
    MatchQ[Mod[i + k, 8], 
     0 | 2 | 4] && (i^2 + j^2 > k^2) && (j^2 + k^2 > 
      i^2) && (i^2 + k^2 > j^2), f[i, j, k], 0], {i, 0, 2^10}, {j, 0, 
   2^10}, {k, 1, 2^2 + 1}]];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the definition of `CirclePlus` is not distributed to parallel kernels.  You can test this using

```
DistributeDefinitions[CirclePlus]
(* {} *)

ParallelEvaluate[Print@Definition[CirclePlus]];

(kernel 1) Null

(kernel 2) Null

(kernel 3) Null

(kernel 4) Null
```

This is because `CirclePlus` is in the `` System` `` context:

```
Context[CirclePlus]
(* "System`" *)
```

There is built-in protection against distributing definitions from `` System` `` (and a number of other contexts), as this could in some cases cause severe problems.  This protection cannot be disabled (at least not without risky deep-reaching changes to the system, see `` Parallel`Parallel`Private`$ourExcludedContexts ``).

I can think of two possible workarounds, none perfect:

- Do not use `CirclePlus`.  Use another symbol that is not in `` System` ``
- Create the definitions on subkernels manually:

  ```
  ParallelEvaluate[
   A_\[CirclePlus]B_ := Mod[{A[[1]] + B[[1]] + A[[2]] B[[3]], A[[2]] + B[[2]], A[[3]] + B[[3]]}, 2]
  ]
  ```

  The problem with this approach is that the definitions must be explicitly re-created every time a new subkernel is started. In some cases, new subkernels are started fully automatically in mid-computation (when it is detected that a subkernel has crashed)

  This situation could be improved using [this undocumented method of setting initialization code for subkernels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131858/12).

Comment: Thanks for the answer I appreciate it. +1.

Answer (score 3):

The glitch seems to be with assigning something to Mathematica's `CirclePlus` which doesn't seem to be auto-shared, as opposed to introducing your own operator.   If instead you did:

```
op[A_, B_] := 
  Mod[{A[[1]] + B[[1]] + A[[2]] B[[3]], A[[2]] + B[[2]], 
    A[[3]] + B[[3]]}, 2];

Conv[m_] := IntegerDigits[Mod[m, 8], 2, 3];
SumD[n_, o_] := (fF[op[Conv[n], Conv[o]]])
Do[fF[IntegerDigits[j, 2, 3]] = j, {j, 0, 7}]

Mapp[0] = {0, 0};
Mapp[1] = {0, 1};
Mapp[2] = {1, 0};
Mapp[3] = {1, 1};

LaunchKernels[2]
```

> {"KernelObject"[1, "local"], "KernelObject"[2, "local"]}

```
ParallelSum[Mapp[SumD[a, b]][[2]], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

> 2

```
Sum[(Mapp@SumD[a, b])[[2]], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

> 2

There is no problem.

---

**Update:** Emphasizing Szabolcs' important comment, and acknowledging that`SetSharedFunction` basically defeats the point of parallelizing if it's key to what you're doing.

Upon prompting by Szalbocs, now withdrawing my nod to `SetSharedFunction[CirclePlus]` if you insist on defining `System` functions.
This was the only way I could get remote kernels to play with a defined CirclePlus without explicit remote evaluations, but evidently it drags us back to basically serial operations, so really can't be recommended even if you *really* want to be using `CirclePlus` instead of your own operator.

From the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSharedFunction.html):

> "A shared function is inefficient for mere code distribution and leads to sequential evaluation."

Also c.f. another of Szalbocs' answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138911/51526) for additional discussion.

Comment: `SetSharedFunction` is not meant for this purpose and will often cause a severe slowdown.  Definition sharing is done using `DistributeDefinitions`, but in this case that won't work because it explicitly excludes ``System` `` context symbols. I am not sure how to work around this without risking automatically distributing ``System` ``-context definitions that really should not be distributed ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer I appreciate it. +1.