# Fail to modify the elements of a global vector in ParallelTable

Tags: parallelization

I want to modify a vector in a Table function, such as

```
vec = {0, 0, 0, 0};
Table[vec[[i]] = i, {i, 1, 4}];
vec
// output {1,2,3,4}
```

however, when I use ParallelTable function to speed up the progress, it fails to work.

```
vec = {0, 0, 0, 0};
ParallelTable[vec[[i]] = i, {i, 1, 4}];
vec
// output {0,0,0,0}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: This can't be fixed without a significant performance degradation (`SetSharedVariable`) because Mathematica uses distributed memory parallelism.  Restructure your algorithms so no global data needs to be written.

Comment: @Szabolcs Can you point to a more elaborated discussion of these points?  Thanks.

Comment: @Alan https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138911/12