# Efficiency of Parallelization

Tags: parallelization

I'm trying to evaluate an expression by a repeated application of a list of rules. Like

`tmp1=exp//.rules;`

Here `exp` is a list. No definitions are made for symbols appearing in `rules` and `exp`. In principle, the calculation can be parallelized by

`tmp1=ParallelTable[xx//.rules, {xx, exp}, Method -> "FinestGrained"];`

However, it is found that the evaluation of `xx//.rules` in the subkernels is much slower. This can be seen by comparing the following two codes:

`tmp1=ParallelTable[(Print[#[[1]]];#[[2]])&@AbsoluteTiming[xx//.rules], {xx, exp}, Method -> "FinestGrained"];
tmp2=Table[(Print[#[[1]]];#[[2]])&@AbsoluteTiming[xx//.rules], {xx, exp}];`

Sorry that I fail to get a simplified example, because the rules are very complicated, and the problem disappears for simplified rules. Similar problems were discussed in the question [parallelization performance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48295/why-wont-parallelize-speed-up-my-code/48296#48296). As was suggested in sec. 3.4 of the answer by Szabolcs, one may try to reevaluate expressions in the subkernels. However, this method doesn't seem to work for rules. Does anyone have some good suggestions?

ps, the Mathematica version on my computer is 11.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2016).

Comment: I think the `Print` probably defeats parallelization completely.

Comment: I agree, `Print` will cause interaction of the subkernels with the main kernel -- and even more important -- with the by far slowest component of _Mathematica_: the frontend.

Comment: @ Henrik Schumacher  Indeed, `Print` will affect the total time for the calculation, but not the time spent on the code inside `Print`. To see this, one can remove `Print`, and  check the final output.