# Why ParallelTable is even slower than Table for large tensor construction?

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra, list-manipulation, parallelization

I would like to create a large rank-4 tensor by using both `Table` and `ParallelTable`.

What is actually constructed is given below:
$\mathcal{L}_{m_1,m_2,V_1,V_2}=i\left(\xi^*_2(m_1,v_1)-\xi^*_2(m_2,v_2)\right)V_d(m_1,v_1)V_d(v_2,m_2)$

where the function $\xi_2(m,v;V)=i\frac{\beta_2^2}{2\beta_1^2}\left[1-\left(e^{\frac{E_{v}-E_m-V/2}{kT}}+1\right)^{-1}\right]\sqrt{4\beta^2_1-(E_{v}-E_m-V/2)^2}$

and matrix elements $V_d(m,v)=\langle m|v\rangle=e^{-\lambda^2/2\Omega^2}\sum_{i=0}^{\nu}\sum_{j=0}^{m}\delta_{m-j,\nu-i}(-1)^j\left(\frac{\lambda}{\Omega}\right)^{i+j}\frac{1}{i!j!}\sqrt{\frac{m!\nu!}{(m-j)!(v-i)!}}$

But I don't know why `ParallelTable` didn't give any improvement on the performance.

[image]
See the code below

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Ns = 41; (*number of basis*)
Nb = 7;
V = 1.84;
\[Lambda] = 0.3;
\[CapitalOmega] = 0.5;
\[Epsilon]0 = 0.5;
\[Beta]1 = 1; \[Beta]2 = 0.05; kT = 0.0259/300*10; (*10K*)
(*Franck-Condon factors*)

FK = E^(-\[Lambda]^2/(2 \[CapitalOmega]^2)) Table[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 0\), \(\[Nu]\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 
        0\), \(m\)]\((KroneckerDelta[m - j, \[Nu] - i])\) 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\), \(j\)] 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((
\*FractionBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(\[CapitalOmega]\)])\), \(i + j\)] 
\*FractionBox[\(1.\), \(\(i!\) \(j!\)\)] 
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(\(m!\) \(\[Nu]!\)\), \(\(\((m - j)\)!\) \(\((\[Nu] - 
             i)\)!\)\)]]\)\), {m, 0, Ns - 1}, {\[Nu], 0, Ns - 1}];
(*Eigenenergies of oscillator*)
Em = Table[\[CapitalOmega] (m + 1/2), {m, 0, Ns - 1}];
(*Eigenenergies of shifted oscillator*)
E\[Nu] = Table[\[CapitalOmega] (\[Nu] + 1/
       2) + \[Epsilon]0 - \[Lambda]^2/\[CapitalOmega], {\[Nu], 0, 
    Ns - 1}];
(*Define elementary functions*)
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, 
   If[x < -300., 1., If[x > 300., 0., 1./(1. + Exp[x])]], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
c\[CapitalGamma]0 = 
  Compile[{{E, _Real}, {qV, _Real}, {\[Beta]1, _Real}, {\[Beta]2, \
_Real}}, If[
    Abs[E - qV/2.] <= 
     2 \[Beta]1, \[Beta]2^2/\[Beta]1^2 Sqrt[
      4 \[Beta]1^2 - (E - qV/2.)^2], 0.], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
\[Xi]2L[E_, V_] := 
  I/2 (1 - cf[(E - V/2)/kT]) c\[CapitalGamma]0[E, 
    V, \[Beta]1, \[Beta]2];
\[Xi]2Lmv = 
Table[\[Xi]2L[E\[Nu][[v + 1]] - Em[[m + 1]], V], {m, 0, Ns - 1}, {v,
 0, Ns - 1}];
Table[ (Conjugate[\[Xi]2Lmv[[m1, 
       V1]]] - \[Xi]2Lmv[[m2, V2]]) (FK[[m1, V1]] FK[[m2, V2]])
   , {m1, 1, Ns}, {V1, 1, Ns}, {m2, 1, Ns}, {V2, 1, 
    Ns}]; // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelTable[ (Conjugate[\[Xi]2Lmv[[m1, 
       V1]]] - \[Xi]2Lmv[[m2, V2]]) (FK[[m1, V1]] FK[[m2, V2]])
   , {m1, 1, Ns}, {V1, 1, Ns}, {m2, 1, Ns}, {V2, 1, 
    Ns}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: Have you read this post?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48295/1871

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. In my case, I assume the ParallelTable can split my data in a correct manner automatically. For a given (m1,m2,v1,v2) the result is unique, shouldn't `ParallelTable` work effectively in this case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know why `ParallelTable` is so slow. But I think that an answer to this would not really help you (things can be like they are for quite stupid reasons...).

What will help you more in the future is this:
It is generally not a good idea to use `Table` or `ParallelTable` for linear algebra or big data processing. Remember: *Mathematica* is an interpreted language. That generally means that loop constructs are quite slow. (Imagine the interpreter as a control freak that wants to check each single loop iteration.) Well, there is JIT compilation, but for some reason, it does not seem to be active here.

So it is often better to use built-in commands that utilize compiled back ends (that are vectorized and parallelized).

As an example, here is another way to compute your array that is almost two orders of magnitude faster:

```
a0 = Table[
     (Conjugate[\[Xi]2Lmv[[m1, V1]]] - \[Xi]2Lmv[[m2, V2]]) (FK[[m1, V1]] FK[[m2, V2]]), 
     {m1, 1, Ns}, {V1, 1, Ns}, {m2, 1, Ns}, {V2, 1, Ns}
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

a1 = Transpose[
     ArrayReshape[
      Times[
       Plus[
        KroneckerProduct[Conjugate[\[Xi]2Lmv], ConstantArray[1., {Ns, Ns}]],
        KroneckerProduct[ConstantArray[-1., {Ns, Ns}], \[Xi]2Lmv]
        ],
       KroneckerProduct[FK, FK]
       ],
      {Ns, Ns, Ns, Ns}
      ],
     {1, 3, 2, 4}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

Max[Abs[a0 - a1]]
```

> 6.67575
>
> 0.08598
>
> 0.

### Edit 1

Of course, compiled code is still faster since it requires fewer copy operations:

```
cg = Compile[{{\[Xi]2Lmv, _Complex, 2}, {FK, _Real, 2}},
   Table[ 
    (Conjugate[Compile`GetElement[\[Xi]2Lmv, m1, V1]] - 
       Compile`GetElement[\[Xi]2Lmv, m2, V2]) (Compile`GetElement[FK, 
        m1, V1] Compile`GetElement[FK, m2, V2]),
    {m1, 1, Compile`GetElement[Dimensions[\[Xi]2Lmv], 1]},
    {V1, 1, Compile`GetElement[Dimensions[\[Xi]2Lmv], 2]},
    {m2, 1, Compile`GetElement[Dimensions[\[Xi]2Lmv], 1]},
    {V2, 1, Compile`GetElement[Dimensions[\[Xi]2Lmv], 2]}
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

a2 = cf[\[Xi]2Lmv, FK]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[a0 - a2]]
```

> 0.035156

> 0. 

But if you do not have to run this several time, the compilation time won't be amortized.

### Edit 2

One of your former (now rolled back) edits showed me that one can exploit the distributive law to save a couple of flops:

```
a2 = Transpose[
     ArrayReshape[
      Subtract[
       KroneckerProduct[Conjugate[\[Xi]2Lmv] FK, FK],
       KroneckerProduct[FK, FK \[Xi]2Lmv]
       ],
      {Ns, Ns, Ns, Ns}
      ],
     {1, 3, 2, 4}
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[a0 - a2]]/Max[Abs[a0]]
```

> 0.054181

> 1.86147*10^-16

The timing is already pretty close to the compiled code. Notice that some (negligible) rounding error is introduced here because the distributive law actually does not hold exactly for floating point numbers.

Comment: Are `Times` and `Plus` essentially faster than `*` and `+`?

Comment: No, but oftentimes  easier to read. `Subtract` is somtimes faster on tensors than `-` because `#1-#2&` behaves like `Plus[#1,Minus[#2]]&`, thus there is one more floating point operation.

Comment: How do you figure out the order ({1,3,2,4} ) in the `Transpose`?

Comment: That's because of the identity `KroneckerProduct[A, B] == 
 Flatten[
  Transpose[TensorProduct[A, B], {1, 3, 2, 4}], {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]`for matrices `A` and `B`.

Comment: Thanks, I realized actually KroneckerProduct[Conjugate[\[Xi]2Lmv] FK, FK]+ KroneckerProduct[FK, FK \[Xi]2Lmv] is enough to generate the correct result.

Comment: If you can avoid `Transpose` and `Reshape` by an alternative data layout, then the better!