# Syntax for parallel processing

Tags: parallelization

I have a Do[] loop that references a few global variables but doesn't modify anything. The only output is appending data to an external file. The order of appending doesn't matter, I just can't have duplicates. How can I make this run in parallel? I've tried ParallelDo and Parallelize but for the life of me I can't figure out the syntax and they give errors. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
List1 = [*list one stuff*];
List2 = [*list two stuff*];
Table1 = [*table one stuff*];
max = Length[List2];

Do[
[*a whole bunch of stuff using data from both lists and the table*];
data >>> "output.txt";,
{i,max}];
```

The code runs perfectly fine this way but if I change Do to ParallelDo it gives a ton of errors such as:

```
Part::partd :  Part specification ComputationalGeometry`List2[[1]] is longer than depth of object.
Part::pkspec1 :  The expression ComputationalGeometry`List2 cannot be used as a part specification.
General::stop :  Further output of Part::partd will be suppressed during this calculation.
Part::partw :  Part 3 of ComputationalGeometry`List2[[1]] does not exist.
```

These were occuring for each kernel running.

I couldn't figure out the syntax for Parallelize at all. My data files are huge so I need all parallel processing to use the same global variables. I can't just start another notebook instance and run them manually, I already have to buy more RAM as is.

Is there any way to manually specify what I want run on each kernel? It would be so easy if I could just write:

```
calc[n_,m_] := Do[
[*a whole bunch of stuff using data from both lists and the table*];
data >>> "output.txt";,
{i,n,m}];

RunParallel[calc[1,250],calc[251,500],calc[501,750],calc[751,1000]];
```

Comment: You may want to start by checking out [Why won't Parallelize speed up my code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48295/27951). For a more specific answer we will probably need to see a bit more of your code. Can you make a minimal working example out of it?

Comment: Writing to disk is, without the kind of hardware found on supercomputers and clusters, an inherently serial operation.  It's also a slow operation and without evidence to the contrary I always (cynical, me!) expect disk i/o to dominate execution times.  Distributing the work across threads / processes / whatever-you-call-them may very well make computation faster but then, ...., well imagine twelve trains leaving the platforms of a large terminus simultaneously and trying to get onto the only outbound main line.  At best the signalling system will ensure orderly serialisation of the trains ...

Comment: Incidentally, I made my previous comment because the answer @MarcoB points us to doesn't explicitly call out i/o as a hindrance to parallel speed up.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark the excellent answer linked is a *"community wiki"*, so we can all contribute to it. Also, new answers will be welcomed.  I think, for instance, that it would be nice to have some *debugging tips* for `Parallel` work.